# NASM Instruction segment conflicting override

Tags: assembly, nasm

Unlike the others, I did use some proper segment registry (such like ds and es), but I still got a 'Instruction has conflicting segment overrides' error.
 And here's my code:

`mov byte [es:di],[ds:si]`

What's wrong with it?
(By the way, don't tell me to use movsb or movsw. I tried and they did not work the way I want.)

Comment: You can't have two memory operands with the MOV instruction. You'll need to move the value through a register.

Comment: What's wrong with using `lodsb`? What does this do that is at odds with your desires?

Comment: It's generally a mistake to use segment overrides when you don't need to. They make the code bigger and slower. If what you're moving is in the same 64kb segment, just set `ds` once at the start of the program, then say `mov al, [si]` then `mov [di], al` to move a byte. As @RossRidge said, you can't move memory to memory except with `movsb`.

Comment: NB why are all these questions being posted by people learning 16-bit assembly? Isn't this a near-useless skill?

Comment: 8/16-bit assembly and instructional machines make excellent pedagogic tools for learning assembly: there's not really that many new concepts in 32-bit or 64-bit programming or architectures; arithmetic, register allocation / lifetime / spilling, carry and other status bits, interrupts, stack, heap, code, bss, memory management / effective address, functions and calling conventions can be learned in 16-bit. In general it also makes it much more difficult to fake completing the exercises, when there's no `gcc -S` for a 16-bit target...